# weird permission for the new user

Tags: permissions

I have came across a situation where I am not sure why a user is getting weird permissions of a user that already removed from the system. I have created a user named harry and gave permission to a folder. I have removed the old user and added another user. Surprisingly the new user that is having the uid of the removed user is getting the permission of the old user had.

```
root@ubuntu2:~# mkdir /root/test
root@ubuntu2:~# ls -ld /root/test/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  1 15:27 /root/test/
root@ubuntu2:~# useradd harry
root@ubuntu2:~# cat /etc/passwd|grep harry
harry:x:1001:1001::/home/harry:
root@ubuntu2:~# chown -R harry:harry /root/test/
root@ubuntu2:~# ls -ld /root/test/
drwxr-xr-x 2 harry harry 4096 Mar  1 15:27 /root/test/
root@ubuntu2:~# userdel harry
root@ubuntu2:~# ls -ld /root/test/
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 1001 4096 Mar  1 15:27 /root/test/
root@ubuntu2:~# useradd tom
root@ubuntu2:~# cat /etc/passwd|grep tom
tom:x:1001:1001::/home/tom:
root@ubuntu2:~# ls -ld /root/test/
drwxr-xr-x 2 tom tom 4096 Mar  1 15:27 /root/test/
```

Here tom got access to the folder test harry had since he is having the same uid of the old user.

Comment: I can confirm this on 14.04 and 14.10, I don't know if this is a bug or us as users should be managing UID's.

Answer (score 0):

*"Here tom got access to the folder test harry had since he is having the same uid of the old user*."

That's precisely how the file system is supposed to work, if you've got the same UID as the old user then you are effectively the same as the old user.

Comment: yes, same uid is the reason for getting the permission. But would it be better to have a dedicated userid for these situations where no user get the permissions automatically and the root should manually assign the permissions to any user who need ?